# What is a good method to define what properties belong to specific types in a given database table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In a forthcoming .Net web-based application we will have several location types, such as Hotel, Restaurant, Airports, all stored in a SQL Server database table.

I want to use one `Locations` table for all locations, but have certain properties tied to specific location types.  This way, when editing hotel properties, we do not want to see properties like Airport Code.

I am thinking that all properties should be listed as columns, then in some configuration class define what properties belong to what `LocationType`.  I'm not sure if this is the way to go and would like some suggestions, and even how to implement this.

Comment: What's the benefit of putting these different things into a single table? Weigh that against the costs of the extra coding you're going to need do just to retrieve and display these types differently inside your application.

Comment: Well, normalization rules will tell you to more type-specific columns to sibling tables, but in practice that can be tricky to manage.  If you want your database to be more compact (denormalized) then I would say your data objects (not the database, but C# classes to map from data to objects) would define the columns that are applicable to a specific type.

Comment: Maybe have a separate table for each type of location? Otherwise, you could have a `Properties` table and `LocationTypeProperties` linking table to keep track of which properties belong to which location types. But then you would still have all available properties in your `Locations` table, which would be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When editing hotel properties, we do not want to see properties like
>   Airport Code

That is an application thing.  You need to manage that at the application level if location is shared or not.

At the database you just have Airport table that has a FK to the Location table.  Can just have a view for airport (and other types) that is a simple join.

In the location table you can have a column for type or not.

One potential problem is a Location could exists in both Hotel and Airport.  If you want to protect this at the database level then a bit of over head.  You can have a composite PK in which type is a component.  Then in the type table that value is restricted to that value.  But then you have the issue of increment the other component of the PK.  I don't think Identity likes being part of a composite key.  I think you could have a sequence for each type.

It would look like this

```
Location  
TypeID     PK FK (to a simple valid types table)  
LocationID PK  

Airport 
TypeID     PK  (hard coded to that TypeID)  
LocationID PK  
FK to Location
```

At the application each Type just implements Location.

If you want to do stuff like find hotel(s) close to airport a single Location table is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your tables.

[image]

Location data will be stored in Location table. Locations which will need airport code will keep corresponding record in AirportCode table.

Comment: I don't agree.  If Location.ID is unique then you don't need a new unique identifier at AirportCode.   This design would allow two airports at the same location and I doubt that is what they want.

Comment: just use locationId and code if you don't need further unique id. and set the locationId as primary key too.

Comment: @Paparazzi - a city could have 1..* airports.

Comment: @ElHaix City? So what!  If a city had multiple airports you would give them all the same Location.ID (and Location.Name).  Good luck with the app.  You seem to be on top of the data model.  What I really mean to say there is a be nice policy.

Comment: @Paparazzi - Thank you for the feedback - appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few standard patterns for this: TPT, TPH, TPC. I assume you are using an ORM. Different ORMs support different patterns. EF does support some. You can use inheritance on the .NET side to only have the relevant properties shown.

This is a fairly big topic. You need to research it. The trade-offs are not trivial.

You can consider going for the simplest solution which is TPH *without* inheritance and just give up on your goal.

Answer (score 0):

you could a Locations table that has all the columns, then use views on top to limit the columns returned for different location types.